# Call to a member function delay() on int

Tags: excel, laravel, sms

With Laravel, how can I get an SMS after 5 minutes after importing Excel?

Not that the text message will come until we import Excel.

I want SMS to come after 5 minutes.

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new OtherImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
    $delay = now()->addMinutes(5);
    Bus::dispatch(new SendSmsJob())->delay($delay);
    return back();
}
```

I get this error.

> Call to a member function delay() on int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because the `delay()` method is being called on the result of `Bus::dispatch(new SendSmsJob())`, which is an integer (the ID of the dispatched job), not a job instance.

In Laravel, you should chain the `delay()` method directly to the job instance before dispatching it.

```php
public function import(Request $request)
{
    Excel::import(new OtherImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
    $delay = now()->addMinutes(5);
    $job = (new SendSmsJob())->delay($delay);
    Bus::dispatch($job);

    return back();
}
```